# DOORS DXL Regular Expressions [match 0] not working

Tags: regex, ibm-doors

This very basic program fails to run under DOORS 9.6.1.6:

```
string t = "Hello World!"
Regexp re = regexp2 ".+([a-z]+!)$"
if(re t){
    print "found the " re[match 0]
}
```

I get this error

```
-E- DXL: <Line:4> incorrect arguments for ([)
-E- DXL: <Line:4> incorrectly concatenated tokens
-I- DXL: All done. Errors reported: 2. Warnings reported: 0.
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t[match 0]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you seem to be right. Interesting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135415/in-doors-dxl-how-do-i-use-a-regular-expression-to-determine-whether-a-string-st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to invode `match` on a regexp object, while you should use it with a string.

Fix it as

```
print "found the " t[match 0]
                   ^
```